# CurrentProject.OpenConnection Fails in MS Access 2000

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2000

I support a LOB application written in MS Access VBA with a SQL Server back end. One feature of the application is the ability to open a second instance of the application, allowing the users to view/modify two records at the same time.

The first time I open the application it connects and everything works fine. However when I attempt to open the second instance I get the following error message:

```
-2147467259 - Method "OpenConnection" of object _CurrentProject failed.
```

This is the line of code executing when the error occurs:

```
CurrentProject.OpenConnection strConnection
```

I have stepped through the code and verified that `strConnection` is the same connection string in both the first and second instances of the application

I'm running out of things to look for. Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:** It appears that something is not allowing the second MSACCESS.EXE instance to use the same connection string. My connection string is below, with `database` and `server` substituted for the actual database and server.

```
PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB.1;INTEGRATED SECURITY=SSPI;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=FALSE;INITIAL CATALOG=database;DATA SOURCE=server
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h32h3abf(v=vs.110).aspx)

Would it be better to open a new form from the same application?

```
dim frm as ShowCar_Form

frm.Show
```